# jQuery .on click event does not occur

Tags: javascript, onclick, jquery, jquery-on

Hi and thanks for reading.  I've been trying to avoid using HTML `onclick="__"` references and instead putting these events in my .js file.  After reading about jQuery's .click() and then .on() events, I tried to use this in my code for a button.

***edit*** In my haste to make up a `<p>` that didn't have the rest of the contents, I entered "name" instead of "id".  Many answers have recommended I either switch to a `p[name=p+` or `#p+` reference, but my main problem has been that I can't even hit the alert before the reference to the id/name.  Thanks again for your answers.

HTML:

```
<p name="pBananas"> junk </p> 
<button class="deleter" id="dBananas" name="Bananas">Delete</button>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleter').click(function() {
        alert('click function works');
        $("p" + $(this).attr("name")).remove();
    });
});
```

The above code won't even get to the alert when I click the button.  I've also tried referring to the button by name and ID, and going by `$(document).ready($('.deleter')___`.

I tried using the `$(handler)` format as well to have the click event be set after the document is ready.  Neither way seems to work.  At this point, I resorted to `onclick="deleteButton()"` and have a `deleteButton()` function in my .js file, but the function won't detect `$(this)` and just deletes all `<p>` tags.

The rest of my javascript is working.  I haven't tried including this `.on()` at the bottom of the HTML, but I'm trying to avoid scripts in my HTML as well.  For completeness' sake, I've been testing on both Chrome and Firefox, using a .jsp file to render the HTML.

Thanks again.

Edits

here's how I'm referencing my jquery and js, directly copy-pasted.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

here is how my html looks leading up to the div where the

is inserted:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">Card Draw Probability Calculator</div>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="cardList">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend> Select cards for probability calculation</legend>

                        <div id="innerCardList"></div>
```

Here is how the `<p>` is generated:

```
function newestCardListLineMaker() {
    var $newLine = $('<p id="newestPara"><input type="checkbox" name="new" value="none"/> <input class="cardText" type="text" maxlength="30" name="newestCard" /> Quantity <input type="text" maxlength="1" class="quantityText" name="newestQuant" /><button class="deleter" id="newestDelete">Delete</button><br/></p>');

    $("#innerCardList").append($newLine);
```

**On another note, which I should have seen before as significant: the HTML that the `.click` or `.on(click, handler)` is referencing has been created by another js function.**

Comment: Check your demo http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.5.2/

Comment: Your code seems to work on standalone check http://jsfiddle.net/ka5zU/

Comment: Did you include a reference to jQuery in your HTML document? And also, is your script.js file BELOW this reference?

Comment: to remove this could be: `$("p[name=p" + $(this).attr("name")+"]").remove();`

Comment: Can i show your code of include js file in your HTML page?

Comment: @ahren I've added my references to .js and jquery in my edits of the post.  Do you think there's a problem there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .on() function, so your code would be:

```
$(document).ready({
  $('.deleter').on('click', function(){
     //do stuff here
  });
});
```

Even better would be this:

```
$(document).ready({
   $('div_above_.deleter').on('click', '.deleter', function(){
     // do stuff here
   });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This answer was closest to helping me figure out the answer.  I needed to delegate the actions because the <p>s were created by js.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ka5zU/1/)**

```
<p id="pBananas"> junk </p> 
    <button class="deleter" id="dBananas" name="Bananas">Delete</button>​

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.deleter').click(function() {
            alert('click function works');
            $("#p" + $(this).attr("name")).hide();
        });
    });​
```

Edited **[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RvuN9/2/)**

Comment: Hi Sibu.  Why are you hiding instead of removing?

Comment: Also... I tried using the #p, but it still won't show the alert or hide the <p>

Comment: @jasonlee remove() will completely remove matched elements from the DOM completely so if you need to show it later you can't. Did you check the jsfiddle link..its working

Comment: I checked the link.  It works in the jsfiddle link, but .click will not work, as I've now tested it, on any element on my page.

Comment: @jasonlee i have edited my answer as your new requirements..though your question was unclear, let me know if you need some other help

Comment: Do you have any ideas on why my project's .click() doesn't actually detect click events?  Your code seems to work well in jsfiddle, but when I move it to my project, it won't work even when the other parts of the script will.

Answer (score 1):

I have modify your javascript code check it.

```
$('.deleter').click(function() {
        alert('click function works');
        var p="p"+$(this).attr("name");
        $('p[name='+p+']').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it works. Didn't delete the Paragraph element though so your code should look like this instead:

```
<p id="pBananas"> junk </p> 
<button class="deleter" id="dBananas" name="Bananas">Delete</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleter').click(function() {
        alert('click function works');
        $("#p" + $(this).attr("name")).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: I see how I might have referred to the paragraph element incorrectly, but why would the alert not show?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - only the alert showed (it did show for me, oddly enough), and just that in your code, paragraph element wasn't removed but alert did show when I tested your exact code as you gave it.

Comment: Unfortunately my problem is that I can't even get to the alert.  I made an edit above noting how the HTML containing the <p> was made after the page has already loaded.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.deleter').click(function() {
        alert('click function works');
        //alert($(this).attr("name"));
        $("p[name=p" + $(this).attr("name") + "]").remove();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The final code I used to complete the `.on('click')` event was:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#innerCardList").on("click", "button.deleter", function() {
        var paraName = $(this).closest("p").attr("id");
        $("#" + paraName).remove();
    });

});
```

The HTML elements which I wanted to assign click events to were generated after the page was already loaded.  I needed to delegate the events to the containing div.

Thanks for all the help and different perspectives!